# How to create a figure with show() via the matplotlib API?

Tags: matplotlib, backend

I need to create a figure object which has can be `show()`'ed on the screen (when using some interactive backend) or `savefig()`'ed, but I need to avoid using the pylab/pyplot API as it sets default backend and messes other things up. I create the figure as

```
import matplotlib.figure
import matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg # or agg for headless backends
figure=matplotlig.figure.Figure()
canvas=matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure)
```

but I am still missing something. The [documentation of Figure.show](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.show) says

```
If the figure was not created using figure(), it will lack a FigureManagerBase, and will raise an AttributeError.
```

How do I do *that* then?

Comment: You need to stick the canvas into a widget window. See http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html

Comment: Yes, but I would like to use some matplotlib's internal function to do all the heavy work (standard windows with zoom buttons etc), just bypassing the pylab API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'standard' window you get in interactive sessions is run via the `figure_manager` family of classes which are tightly to `pyplot`.

Fortunately, all of the zoom/pan functionality is wrapped up in the `NavigationToolbar` family of classes.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar

def create_main_frame(self):
    # host widget
    self.main_frame = QtGui.QWidget()
    # set up the mpl side of things
    self.fig = Figure((24, 24), tight_layout=True)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
    # attach canvas to host widget
    self.canvas.setParent(self.main_frame)
    # make axes
    self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111, adjustable='datalim', aspect='equal')
    # make the tool bar
    self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.main_frame)

    # set up layout
    vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(self.mpl_toolbar)
    vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)
    # set the layout to the host widget
    self.main_frame.setLayout(vbox)
    # make the host widget the central widget in the main frame of the class
    # this code is ripped from
    self.setCentralWidget(self.main_frame)
```